# Win 10 notifications in python without new tray icon for each notification

Tags: python, notifications, windows-10, pywin32

I came across [zroya](https://github.com/malja/zroya/blob/master/zroya/__init__.py) which is a wrapper around the windows 10 notifications. I noticed it also created an empty tray icon for each new notification, so I've just been attempting to merge it with [my existing tray icon code](https://pastebin.com/1YS58qns), hoping it'd fix that issue.

Unfortunately now I've added the basic functionality, I've found it doesn't, and was wondering if anyone could share any tips on what I could do.

I believe the part of the code causing the issue is this, which is called each time a notification is created:

```
nid = (self.hwnd, notification_id, flags, win32con.WM_USER + 1, icon, 'Tooltip')
win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_ADD, nid)

win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_MODIFY, (
    self.hwnd, notification_id, win32gui.NIF_INFO,
    win32con.WM_USER + 1,
    icon,
    'Tooltip',
    message,
    0,
    title,
    additional_flags
))
```

This is how I create the actual tray icon that I want to use, which is awfully similar, but without a notification ID being passed in:

```
flags = win32gui.NIF_ICON | win32gui.NIF_MESSAGE | win32gui.NIF_TIP
nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER + 20, hicon, self.program_name)
win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_ADD, nid)
```

If I delete the first 2 lines of the notification code, and change `notification_id` to `0`, then it fixes that particular issue, but instead of the notification event (`WM_USER+1`), it runs under the tray icon event (`WM_USER+20`). I checked the `l_param` value against `win32con` for the ID and found the only events triggered this way are to do with drawing rectangles, so I'm unable to run any of the callback functions.

I'm mostly just getting this working through trial and error since both bits of code are quite similar and I'm not clued up with the Windows API, this bit has me stumped though. I wouldn't recommend looking as it's a mess but here's the current stage of my [merge attempt](https://pastebin.com/tgL520zS). The callbacks are working but only with that separate tray icon.